# WFS Query in QGIS to load features within 1km of points stored locally

Tags: qgis, wfs

I have a points layer saved locally containing sites of interest. I would like to be able to load features from a WFS source that are within 1km of my local layer. I'm looking for something similar to the following in the build query option of the add WFS layer dialog:

```
SELECT wfs.* FROM wfs, local_points
WHERE ST_DWithin(wfs.geometry, local.geometry, 1000)
```

However, this throws an error that local_points is unknown. I'm guessing that is because QGIS is own looking for tables on the WFS. Can it look for local tables? Is there any way of achieving what I want? Requesting features that overlap the current extents isn't suitable as the sites are a long distance apart and I'd end up downloading most of the feature set from the WFS.